# segfault: ubuntu (10.04.4 amd64) and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, wkhtmltopdf

Older (0.10 & 0.11) builds and the current (0.12) one of wkhtmltopdf stopped working on ubuntu (10.04.4 server amd64) systems since the latest kernel update.

It seems wkhtmltopdf tries to read data inside /proc which causes a segfault due to chroot issues/restrictions. I'm currently trying to compile a new version for ubuntu 10.04.4 hoping that this might help.

Anyone experience the same problem?

Comment: You should probably update Ubuntu since it only has 1 year of support left. But as a quick fix, why not just revert to an older kernel version? Usually older kernel versions are not deleted when a new kernel is installed, just change your grub configuration to use the older version instead for now until you update Ubuntu.

Comment: Kernel revert is no option since its a managed server (all-inkl.com). I've compiled a ne wkhtmltopdf 0.12 inside a virtual machine with ubuntu 10.04.4 - works like a charme but not on the managed server.

Comment: hey do you have that binary . It is so big to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem:

There seems to be a bug/restriction issue. With the flag

> --disable-javascript

all binaries are working again.